# Is there a log I can see the first time I unlock my machine every day?

Tags: login, event-log

I would like to, retrospectively, determine my arrival times at the office. Is there an event log somewhere that would record the PC being unlocked. For that matter, being started up?

If I examine the security log, I see no less than 26 *Logon* and *Special Logon* events. I would rather examine a set of events involving me and my desktop than all the behind the scenes service type events.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to create a custom view showing EventID **4101** from the **Application** log.

This is the windows license validation that happens every time you log on to the computer.

Looking at my own list, i have 6 events from the last 5 days, all in the morning when i've logged on,

Comment: I get zero 4101 events.